# $R$ is a commutative ring, $|R| = 30$. If $I$ an ideal with $|I| = 10$, show that $I$ is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring and $|R|=30$. If $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and $|I|=10$, prove that $I$ is maximal ideal.

What we do is: we consider an ideal $J$ that properly contains $I$. So $|I|>10$.
also lagrange theorem is applicable here so $|J|$ must divide $30$ so $|J|=30$.
My question is that why do we rule out $|J|=15$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $10$ does not divide $15$, a group of size $10$ cannot be a subgroup of a group of size $15$. The subgroup of order $15$ forms another maximal ideal. (It just so happens that there is exactly one abelian group of order 30, so we can say *the* subgroup of order $15$).

Comment: I imagine there is in fact just one *ring* of order $30$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez this is embarassing, but I know absolutely nothing about classifications of rings. Is it true that there is just one ring of order $30$? I suppose this is really asking how many different multiplication structures we can put on the group. But it's not obvious to me how answer that.

Comment: The underlying abelian group is a direct sum of three cyclic groups, and these are ideals (because one of them, for example, is the subset $10R$) So the ring is the direct product of these three subrings (they are unitary rings but not with the same unit as $R$: write $1=e_2+e_3+e_5$ with each summand in each direct summand) Since the three summands have prime order, they don't have any non-zero proper ideals so they are fields. That leaves no choice.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Ah! I learned something today. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Recall that an ideal is maximal if and only if the quotient ring is a field.  Here, $R/I$ is a ring with $|R|/|I| = 30/10 = 3$ elements, and is thus a field.  It follow that $I$ is maximal.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to look at it:

Suppose we have $I \subset J \subset R$. It follows (from the fact that an ideal is an additive subgroup) that $J$ is a divisor $d$ of $30$ with:

$10 < d < 30$.

But $I$ is an additive subgroup of $J$, so that $10|d$.

So no such $J$ exists.